# Low res mesh with Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have to work with a mesh I didn't created. The problem is that I can't subdivide it because when I do that, a lots of bugs happened. So I have to use the mesh with it not very high resolution. When I put light on it on Eevee, I can see all the differents faces of the mesh, it's really not uniform. Also, when I set the shape to Smooth, it create other problemes on the shape. Somebody have an idea how to fix that (a trick with the light or a trick with the shape ?).
[image]
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried using smooth shading (*Object > Shade Smooth*)?

Comment: Set the shading on the mesh as a whole to smooth, and then under Object Data Properties > Normals, enable 'Auto Smooth'

Comment: looks actually pretty high-res...

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is this:

### **Instead of using *smooth-surface* to smooth the object, adjust normal-smoothing angle**

Here are the steps:

1) Go to edit mode with the fan selected, and then go to **Mesh > normals > recalculate outside**.
(This is to ensure that normal-smoothing will not ruin the topology.)

2) Right-click (2.80+), or select smooth-shading on the left (2.79-), and select "smooth-shading". This will allow you to smooth the normals.

3) Swap back to object mode, and go to the vertex tab in the properties section. 
Check the box that says Normals-*autosmooth*. Adjust this value.
Lower for less smoothing, and higher for more smoothing.

Here is a sphere at 0 degrees, 50 degrees, and 180 degrees:

0 degrees:

[image]

50 Degrees:

[image]

180 Degrees:

[image]

It's kind of hard to see the 180 degree effects on the sphere, so this is on a cube:

[image]

Comment: This is a very good idea, as it takes into account shading of sharp edges :). +1